# iOS Swift how do I reset/revoke app permissions programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-permissions

iOS Swift how do I reset/revoke app permissions from code.

I am trying to implement notification permission permission programatically.
as a reverse I am also trying to find the code to revert back the permission.

Comment: is the default one, we can't handle

Comment: The whole idea is that a human gives permission to an app so no you can't set or reset that from within your app.

Comment: i think its possible check the link - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions/#permissions-revoking

Answer (score 4):

Once a user has granted (or denied) permissions by responding to the original permission request dialog, the only way that the permissions can be changed is by the user themselves using the device settings app.